# In Word 2016, what is the difference between blue and black paragraph markers?

Tags: microsoft-word

In a Word 2016 document, when show hidden formatting symbols is turned on, sometimes the paragraph markers are blue, and sometimes they're black. Is there a difference between blue and black paragraph markers, and if so, what is it?

See attached screenshot.

[image: paragraph_markers]

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a difference between blue and black paragraph markers?

A paragraph marker will use the colour (and style) applied to the empty paragraphs.

To verify this type some text before the blue paragraph marker.

If the blue colour is not the normal color of the text, select the paragraph mark and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to reset the font formatting.